# How does one get config into volumes for ECS tasks?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I tend to use a bootstrap task which basically puts config in a volume ( gets it from S3 etc ) and then the main task mounts this volume .

Is there a better way to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

One other way to achieve this would be to map an EFS volume in your tasks. It's a bit more work to add the volume in the task definition (+ creating the volume out of band) but it may be worth doing it for getting rid of the init task. [This blog series](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/) talk about the why and how of ECS/EFS.